# Sleep for milliseconds

Tags: c++, linux, sleep

I know the POSIX `sleep(x)` function makes the program sleep for x seconds. Is there a function to make the program sleep for x *milliseconds* in C++?

Comment: You should be aware that, in Windows anyway, `Sleep()` has millisecond *precision*, but it's *accuracy* can be orders of magnitude higher.  You may think your sleeping for 4 milliseconds, but actually sleep for 400.

Comment: @John Dibling: I think he's using POSIX `sleep`, not win32 `Sleep` given "x seconds".

Comment: Although C and C++ have different name mangling, which can be a source of bugs and incompatibilities, in most cases it's fine to use C headers in C++. However, if you want to be absolutely sure that nothing goes wrong, `#include` the C header inside an `extern "C" {}` block. Also, if you have C and C++ source files in the same project, it's highly recommended that you do this in order to avoid any problems, especially if you include the same headers in both kinds of source files (in which case this is necessary). If you have a purely C++ project, it might just work with no problem at all.

Comment: @JohnDibling no, not 400ms. The worst precision you might ever have gotten was from Windows 9x, whose `GetTickCount` had 55ms resolution; later versions had 16ms resolution or less. One user [thought he was getting 16ms resolution from Sleep](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0430f043-443d-451a-bf6b-10de6bfeba29/sleep-function-is-not-accurate?forum=Vsexpressvc) but then reported that `Sleep` itself was fairly accurate, and the apparent imprecision was caused by using `GetTickCount` to measure the passage of time.

Comment: I had just fallen into this MS trap in Windows 10. Using the QueryPerformanceCounter a Sleep(1) returns after about 14 ms.

Comment: There's `usleep()` on POSIX compliant platforms..

Comment: @Qwertie: On a busy system, with other processes waiting to run, your process might not get scheduled again for a fair while after its wakeup time.  Of course this could have happened after it got pre-empted if it didn't sleep before using up its timeslice, but it's worth mentioning as a warning: once people start writing code with short sleeps, it's easy to forget that it's just a minimum sleep time, not something you can rely on in all conditions.  e.g. you might assume that 10x 100ms sleeps will add up to about a second, but you should check clock_gettime against an older timestamp.

Comment: And as [Is usleep() in C implemented as busy wait?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8158862) points out, for some APIs like `usleep`, the time isn't even a lower bound: a signal can wake the thread earlier.

Answer (score 527, accepted):

Note that there is no standard C API for milliseconds, so (on Unix) you will have to settle for `usleep`, which accepts microseconds:

```
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned int microseconds;
...
usleep(microseconds);
```

Comment: Is it a busy sleep? I need to yield to another thread during sleep; can I use `usleep` for that?

Comment: It's not a busy wait http://stackoverflow.com/a/8156644/1206499, and `nanosleep`may be a better choice since `usleep` is obsolete.

Comment: Niet, please consider mentioning @HighCommander4's answer which is more portable if you have a C++11 compiler.

Comment: usleep() deprecated in POSIX in 2001 and removed in 2008.

Comment: Apparently `usleep()` is deprecated, so [I wrote an example here to show how to write your own `sleep_us()` (or `usleep()`) function as a wrapper around `nanosleep()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053788/implicit-declaration-of-function-usleep/55860234#55860234).

Answer (score 1711):

In C++11, you can do this with standard library facilities:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
```

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
```

Clear and readable, no more need to guess at what units the `sleep()` function takes.

Comment: Does std::this_thread::sleep_for define an interruption point? Like boost::this_thread_sleep does?

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Period. Thread is cross platform as well as chrono.

Comment: @Void. A very good way certainly, but "the" and "period" are awfully strong words.

Comment: this method is not the best because it has delay, as mentioned in [Note that multi-threading management may cause certain delay beyond this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/)

Comment: @Valen: Is there another method that avoids such delays?

Comment: @HighCommander4 , probably not, or need to travel inside the os, or use a single core, single thread processor lol.

Comment: Is it a busy sleep? I need to yield to another thread during sleep; can I use `sleep_for` for that?

Comment: @Michael: It's not a busy sleep, it will yield to other threads.

Comment: @Void If possible, certainly! But if you can't use C++11, or if you're compiling without standard library support, you must do something else.

Comment: I support @Valen in that way, that a much better name for the method would be std::this_thread::REQUEST_reactivation_after(...). But this is called sleep as long everyone can think of ...

Comment: @Michael what is meant by `busy_sleep`?

Comment: Is this interruptable with a signal?

Comment: @Abhinav Gauniyal It means checking very frequently if it should start again, therefore using a lot of CPU doing nothing. As you probably guessed, this is usually undesirable, especially when you have other threads that have actual work to do.

Comment: Is there any rule or reason why one of us can't just edit the accepted answer to say what this answer says? This is the correct answer after all.

Comment: @MartinMeeser, no the standard did not choose to support the interruption point feature of Boost threads at all.

Comment: Does it bother anyone else to have a statement with this_thread, just for a sleep function. It really throws me off to include <thread> when there is no threading in my program

Comment: Are you sure the actual minimum time isn't 15-16 ms in some cases (even if e.g. 3 ms is specified)? Have you measured it (e.g. with the high-resolution timer)?

Comment: From C++11 you can use even shorter form using numeric literals `std::this_thread::sleep_for(123ms);`. See my other post here.

Comment: regarding "the right way": Original question asked for C++. Since C++11, this is the definitive answer. Alternatives (like nanosleep, or usleep) are POSIX, and thus they are C solutions and portable to the degree that POSIX is. Both solutions have in common that they rely on the OS scheduler, and thus typically add granularity and a "at least" condition. For high precision, use a busy wait on a high resolution timer.

Comment: How can you cancel this sleep - without implementing a busy-wait

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi Presumably there is another thread involved to trigger the cancellation. In such cases, you would typically use a condition variable as described e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29775639). If that does not answer your question, probably best to ask it in a new question rather than a comment.

Comment: @HighCommander4 Thanks. I was concerned with `condition_variable` busy waiting (which I found was true when doing some research some months ago). However, It's much easier to use the std apis than having to implement my own OS-specific impls, so until I reach the performance issues I was concerned about, I'll go with that solution

Answer (score 86):

To stay portable you could use [Boost::Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) for sleeping:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

int main()
{
    //waits 2 seconds
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::seconds(1) );
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000) );

    return 0;
}
```

*This answer is a duplicate and has been posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103707/need-a-better-wait-solution/4103842#4103842) before. Perhaps you could find some usable answers there too.*

Comment: Keep in mind that - in a multi-threaded environment -`boost::this_thread::sleep` adds an interruption point to your code.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html

Answer (score 43):

In Unix you can use [`usleep`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/usleep.html).

In Windows there is [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: and the Windows call is in milliseconds.

Comment: You have to include <unistd.h> or <Windows.h> respectively.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't the actual time resolution be 15-16 ms (even if the unit in the call is 1 ms) and thus the minimum time be 15-16 ms?

Answer (score 39):

From C++14 using std and also its numeric literals:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::this_thread::sleep_for(123ms);
```

Comment: How is this implemented?  `123ms` looks weird.

Comment: In short, it is implemented as user-defined literal, similarly as you define other operators:

    long double operator "" ms(long double)

In my opinion is is better readable than `chrono::milliseconds(1000)`.
See [User-defined literals][1] for more info.

[1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Answer (score 33):

Depending on your platform you may have `usleep` or `nanosleep` available. `usleep` is deprecated and has been deleted from the most recent POSIX standard; `nanosleep` is preferred.

Comment: Note that while `usleep()` is declared in `<unistd.h>`, confusingly, `nanosleep()` is declared in `<time.h>`/`<ctime>`.

Answer (score 29):

Why don't use `time.h` library? Runs on Windows and POSIX systems (don't use this code in production!):

CPU stays in IDLE state:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif // _WIN32

using namespace std;

void sleepcp(int milliseconds);

void sleepcp(int milliseconds) // Cross-platform sleep function
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
        Sleep(milliseconds);
    #else
        usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
    #endif // _WIN32
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Hi! At the count to 3, I'll die! :)" << endl;
    sleepcp(3000);
    cout << "urrrrggghhhh!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: @BartGrzybicki i know this is an old answer and all, but in Visual Studio 2017 on a windows machine, `#ifdef WIN32` doesn't evaluate as true by-default.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck Code is wrong. It should be `#ifdef _WIN32`.

Comment: @Contango I knew that! But not when I wrote that... lol. Thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score 18):

`nanosleep` is a better choice than `usleep` - it is more resilient against interrupts.

Comment: I was familiar with `usleep`, but not `nanosleep`. You should provide an example of using it on Linux.

Answer (score 18):

```
#include <windows.h>
```

**Syntax:**

```
Sleep (  __in DWORD dwMilliseconds   );
```

**Usage:**

```
Sleep (1000); //Sleeps for 1000 ms or 1 sec
```

Comment: What do you need to include for this?

Comment: `#include <WinBase.h>`

Comment: No, you need to `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: The question strongly implies that a POSIX solution is required.

Answer (score 6):

If using MS Visual C++ 10.0, you can do this with standard library facilities:

```
Concurrency::wait(milliseconds);
```

you will need:

```
#include <concrt.h>
```

Comment: Don't use the word "standard" when you don't actually mean it.  `<concrt.h>` is *not* a Standard Library header - it may be a platform library; in which case you should state the prerequisites clearly.

Comment: Not only that, but we'd expect a [tag:linux] question to be using one of the popular compilers.

Comment: Cannot be used with CLR (compiler option /clr).

Comment: This was posted in 2015.  Is there any reason you'd ever use this instead of `std::chrono`?  Perhaps a codebase that wasn't ready to move to C++11 yet?  I assume it's pretty much obsolete in 2023.

Answer (score 5):

On platforms with the `select` function (POSIX, Linux, and Windows) you could do:

```
void sleep(unsigned long msec) {
    timeval delay = {msec / 1000, msec % 1000 * 1000};
    int rc = ::select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &delay);
    if(-1 == rc) {
        // Handle signals by continuing to sleep or return immediately.
    }
}
```

However, there are better alternatives available nowadays.

Comment: Can't seem to compile in VS2017 on a Windows machine: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _select@20 referenced in function "void __cdecl sleep(unsigned long)" (?sleep@@YAXK@Z)`

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck It does compile. Just doesn't link. Lookup you Windows docs.

Comment: what header do you use for timeval ??

Comment: @TotteKarlsson `<sys/time.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

Select call is a way of having more precision (sleep time can be specified in nanoseconds).

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 3):

The way to sleep your program in C++ is the `Sleep(int)` method. The header file for it is `#include "windows.h."`

For example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 6000;
    Sleep(x);
    cout << "6 seconds have passed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The time it sleeps is measured in milliseconds and has no limit.

```
Second = 1000 milliseconds
Minute = 60000 milliseconds
Hour = 3600000 milliseconds
```

Comment: What do you mean it has no limit? It surely has limit which is 0xFFFFFFFE. Waiting for 0xFFFFFFFF will just not time out (which means it will wait till program ends).

Comment: I didn't mean it like that Izzy, sorry for our misunderstanding. I meant that you can enter any positive number of milliseconds. So it will wait that many milliseconds to close the program. If you do not understand please say so, I shall explain to you more.

Comment: Yes, but what it the actual time resolution? Couldn't it be 15-16 ms in some cases? E.g., if you use Sleep(3) will it actually sleep for 3 ms or will it instead be 15-16 ms?

Comment: I don't think "windows.h" is a standard POSIX or Linux header...

Comment: _"The way to sleep your program in C++ is the `Sleep(int)` method"_ - That was a pretty odd thing to write in 2014, 3 years after C++11 was released.

Answer (score 1):

Use Boost asynchronous input/output threads, sleep for x milliseconds;

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::thread::sleep(boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::millisec(1000));
```

Comment: What will actually happen if you try to sleep for 3 milliseconds? Will it be 15-16 milliseconds instead? Have you measured it?

Answer (score 1):

Elegant solution from the one answer, bit modified.. One can easilly add select() usage if there's no better functionality available. Just make function that uses select() etc. ..

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

/*
 Prepare defines for millisecond sleep function that is cross-platform
*/
#ifdef _WIN32
#  include <Windows.h>
#  define sleep_function_name           Sleep
#  define sleep_time_multiplier_for_ms      1
#else
#  include <unistd.h>
#  define sleep_function_name           usleep
#  define sleep_time_multiplier_for_ms      1000
#endif

/* Cross platform millisecond sleep */
void cross_platform_sleep_ms(unsigned long int time_to_sleep_in_ms)
{
   sleep_function_name ( sleep_time_multiplier_for_ms * time_to_sleep_in_ms );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a Win32 replacement for POSIX systems:

```
void Sleep(unsigned int milliseconds) {
    usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
}

while (1) {
    printf(".");
    Sleep((unsigned int)(1000.0f/20.0f)); // 20 fps
}
```

Comment: Prefer `nanosleep()` to `usleep()`: the latter is deprecated and has been deleted from the most recent POSIX standard.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but I managed to figure out a simple way to have this in my app. You can create a C/C++ macro as shown below use it:

```
#ifndef MACROS_H
#define MACROS_H

#include <unistd.h>

#define msleep(X) usleep(X * 1000)

#endif // MACROS_H
```

Comment: You probably meant `usleep((X) * 1000)` - which is one reason why functions are so much better than macros!

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, if it will be an expression where you sum up two number msleep(1 + 2), then the macro substitution will be  usleep(1 + 2 * 1000)   will be 2001  instead of  3000
Making usleep ((X) * 1000) , guarantees that (1+2) will be evaluated first.  Just for those who are not aware, though it is basics of macros. Don't use them especially if you are not aware of how they work in principle.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
#include <thread>
#define sleepms(val) std::this_thread::sleep_for(val##ms)
```

example:

```
sleepms(200);
```