# Is usleep() in C implemented as busy wait?

Tags: c, posix

I'm building a multithreaded application with `pthreads` and need a thread to periodically check some stuff. During the time in between this thread shouldn't use any CPU. Is this possible with `usleep()`? Is `usleep()` not busy waiting? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: I think pthreads has a [`yield()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) feature that might be useful.

Comment: `usleep` has nothing to do with C as a language, it is a feature of the operating system.

Comment: @KerrekSB: `pthread_yield` won't decrease CPU usage, it will just cause the thread to be temporarily deprioritized relative to other threads of the same priority level.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function `usleep` has been removed from SUSv4. You should probably use `nanosleep` instead or timers (`setitimer`, etc).

As R.. notes in the comments, should the sleep be implemented as a busy wait:

- The thread would continue to use the CPU
- Other (lower-priority) threads wouldn't get a chance to run

Thus:

- Some might use signals (I think SUSv3 mentioned SIGALARM?)
- Some might use fancy timers

Comment: `usleep` is not part of the C library, AFAIK.

Comment: @JensGustedt It's not standard. But `libc` (glibc, bsd libc etc) usually has it. So, if anybody has it, it's the C library.

Comment: it *is* standard but POSIX :)

Comment: right, I thought it only was deprecated, I'll change my answer

Comment: @JensGustedt `kernel.org` mentiones it not being in SUSv4. And searching SUSv4 for it yields nothing.

Comment: It cannot be implemented as a busy wait because that would preclude allowing for other lower-priority threads/processes to run.

Comment: @R.. I'll incorporate that into my answer :-)

Answer (score 13):

(`usleep` is not part of the C standard, but of an ancient POSIX standard. But see below.)

No, the POSIX specification of `usleep` clearly states

> The usleep() function will cause the calling thread to be suspended
>   from execution ...

so this clearly requires that it suspends execution and lets the resources to other processes or threads.

As already be mentioned by others, the POSIX function `nanosleep` is now replacing `usleep` and you should use that. C (since [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29)) has a function `thrd_sleep` that is modeled after `nanosleep`.

Answer (score 8):

Just be aware that both usleep() and nanosleep() can be interrupted by a signal.  nanosleep() lets you pass in an extra timespec pointer where the remaining time will be stored if that happens.  So if you really need to guarantee your delay times, you'll probably want to write a simple wrapper around nanosleep().

Beware that this is not tested, but something along these lines:

```
int myNanoSleep(time_t sec, long nanosec)
{
   /* Setup timespec */
   struct timespec req;
   req.tv_sec = sec;
   req.tv_nsec = nanosec;

   /* Loop until we've slept long enough */
   do 
   {
      /* Store remainder back on top of the original required time */
      if( 0 != nanosleep( &req, &req ) )
      {
          /* If any error other than a signal interrupt occurs, return an error */
          if(errno != EINTR)
             return -1; 
      }
      else
      {
          /* nanosleep succeeded, so exit the loop */
          break;
      }
   } while( req.tv_sec > 0 || req.tv_nsec > 0 )
   return 0; /* Return success */
}
```

And if you ever need to wake the thread for something other than a periodic timeout, take a look at condition variables and `pthread_cond_timedwait()`.

Comment: This has always amused, as in POSIX sleep functions the requested time not only is not an upper bound (since, as on other operating systems, the system is free to reschedule your thread as later as it wants), but is not even a lower bound due to signals. Essentially, sleep-like functions can return whenever they like most. :-D

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, it is implemented with the [nanosleep system call](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) which is not a busy wait.

Using [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace), I can see that a call to `usleep(1)` is translated into `nanosleep({0, 1000}, NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

`usleep()` is a C runtime library function built upon system timers.
`nanosleep()` is a system call.

Only MS-DOS, and like ilk, implement the sleep functions as busy waits.  Any actual operating system which offers multitasking can easily provide a sleep function as a simple extension of mechanisms for coordinating tasks and processes.