# CPU Utilization on Redhat 6

Tags: c, linux

I did the following code snippet on redhat 6:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while(true)
    {
#ifdef SLEEP
        sleep(1);
#endif
#ifdef USLEEP
        usleep(1000);
#endif
     }

    return 0;
}
```

It is supposed to sleep the exact same maount since 1000 us = 1 ms
On redhat 6 the one with sleep takes 0% utilization all the time.
The one with usleep takes between 1.5% to 2% all the time. I have many of those all over the server i am maintaining.
Any explanation for why usleep is much more cpu sensitive on redhat 6?
On redhat 5 i see no differences.
By the way in general i am seeing that on redhat 6 the CPU is much more sensitive. Any known issues around that?

Comment: `usleep` takes argument as **microsecond** and not millisecond. 1000000 microsecond equals 1 second. so call as `usleep( 1000000 )`

Comment: Please read my comment below on answer 1. 1000 us = 1 ms

Comment: @issac please read my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usleep parameter is MILLIONTHS of seconds, not thousandths.  micro vs milli.

Add three more zeroes and I think you'll see what you expect.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep

**The usleep() function suspends execution of the calling thread for (at least) usec microseconds**

Comment: 1000 microseconds is exactly one 1 millisecond so the above waits the exact same amount of time. Sleep in C (unlike bash) waits in milliseconds so 1000 us is exactly 1 ms so the above is supposed to wait the exact same amount of time

Comment: No... `sleep()` in C takes an argument in seconds. It works exactly like the shell builtin.

Answer (score 0):

`sleep` takes its argument as **seconds** while `usleep` takes its argument as **microseconds**.

To mention,

```
1 second = 1000 milli-second
1 milli-second = 1000 micro-second
```

Means, unlike you expected, `usleep( 1000 )` will not have similar wait time as `sleep( 1 )`.

`usleep( 1000 )` version will loop more frequent than `sleep( 1 )` version causing more CPU usage.

To have similiar wait time of nearly 1 second, use either `sleep( 1 )` or `usleep( 10000000 )` .

*I don't have enough information on comparing redhat 5 and 6, or implementation of usleep. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156603/is-usleep-in-c-implemented-as-busy-wait) may give you some information, however.*