# Using a timer in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I've searched over the internet for a function that can "hold" my program..

I've seen the function `sleep()`, though it does not work for me, saying it is undeclared..
(I have included stdlib.h/time.h/iostream)

I do not have parrel stuff that are working in the side, so even if I stop the whole program, that's okay..

for example :

`sleep(3000)`
`cout << "Hello World";`

Thanks!

Comment: Try this dude:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds

Read it.  Hint:  Look for usleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Sleep" with a capital S..... and #include winbase.h

Answer (score 2):

If you are using c++11 you have a portable way to suspend your thread:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

otherwise you have to include Windows.h to use Sleep:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention I have included windows.h too, though it still says it is undeclared..

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
usleep(microseconds)
```

1000 microseconds in a millisecond

You may need to:   `#include <unistd.h>`