# how to send a flag each X minutes?

Tags: c++, measurement

I am working in a kind of "control block" that has to send a flag each 6 minutes. The thing is that I don't know if there is a simple way of doing this. I have had though in use clock_t inside a loop till it reaches the 6 minutes, and then call a method that sends the flag and re-initialize the clock_t variable.

**I forgot to explain something, sleep is not an option because the block works like a flow, it has to send something the whole time. Actually the flag will change what is sending**

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about starting a separate thread just for the `sleep`-ing?

Answer (score 1):

You can just sleep the thread for 6 minutes and then send the flag:

```
for(;;)
{
    sendFlag();
    sleep(6*60);
}
```

[Here are some options for the sleep method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds), including C++11's [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to explain something, sleep is not an option because the block works like a flow, it has to send something the whole time. Actually the flag will change what is sending

Comment: @xuandl: Luchian's solution will not stop you doing that, as the sleep is running under a separate thread, but it does imply that you'll need to understand multi-threading and thread synchronization. It's not clear from your question whether you were anticipating that.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a thread function that switches a flag on or off and sleep it for 6 minutes at a time.  For example:

```
bool flag = false;

int main() {
    while(true) {
        if (flag == true) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    return(0);
}

void threadFunc() {
    flag = true;
    sleep(360); //360 seconds is 6 minutes
}
```

NOTE: You will need to use a mutex or semaphore because the code written now is **not thread safe**.  How you use threads is also operating system dependent.  Unless you use C++11 of course.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a whole thread just for this.  Use a system OS periodic timer callback.