# Using `sleep()` for a time delay

Tags: c, delay, sleep, flappy-bird-clone

I an trying to delay program execution for 200ms and then test if a key was pressed during the delay. How do I do this?

I am tryint to create a simple computer game similar to flappy birds, using C. I want the user to have tiny bit of time (~200ms) to press a key for the bird to jump, or it will fall down, but I am having trouble with implementing the delay.

I've read on some forums <sup>[where?]</sup> that `sleep(100)` should give a 100ms delay, but when I do it, I get 100 seconds.

I also tried using `sleep(1/5)`, but the function only takes integers.

Additionally, I need to be able to test if a key was pressed during the 200ms; I read somewhere<sup>[where?]</sup>  that the `kbhit` function can be used for that, but I have no idea how to use it.

```
while(!dead) {
    sleep(200); // what do I put here to get 200ms?

    if (keyWasPressedDuringWait()){ //what do I put here?
        notDeadAnimation():
    }else{
        dead=true;
        deadAimation()
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds

Comment: Search for [`usleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) or [`nanosleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) (the second one is preferred).

Comment: Try usleep. see `man usleep` for more details.

Comment: If goolging for "khbit" is unsusseccful, try googlign for "kbhit".

Comment: This could have been answered for yourself by reading the documentation provided for your implementation of the standard library or by using google [`sleep function c`](https://www.google.com/search?q=sleep+function+c). It is a classic RTFM. If your documentation is even remotely good it would include a see-also entry for the finer grained functions.

Answer (score 3):

To perform the desired delay, `#include <unistd.h>` and use `usleep(microseconds)`. (To sleep for 200ms, the call is `usleep(200000)`).

To test the keyboard strike, `#include <conio.h>` and use `_kbhit()` in your test (short for **k**ey**b**oard **hit**). `_kbhit` tests if there is a key in the key buffer, but does not get rid of it. You also need to use `_getch` to retrieve the key, removing it from the key buffer. I'd recommend defining a helper function here:

```
int clearKeyBuffer(){
    int count = 0;
    while(_kbhit()){
        _getch();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This method will clear all keys currently in the key buffer, and return the number of keys cleared. You can then use this in your test, as `if(clearKeyBuffer())` to test if a key has been presses since the last time you tested it.

As for your program flow, you have a lot of extra stuff there. You can get rid of most of it and still be functionally identical:

```
do {
    notDeadAnimation();
    usleep(200000);
} while(clearKeyBuffer());

deadAnimation();
```

However, this has the obvious issue that someone could just

Comment: Note that conio.h is probably limited to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Use usleep() instead of sleep(). The former works in micro seconds.
And use _kbhit()+getch() to discover if a key was pressed and which key was it:

```
while (!dead) {
    usleep(200*1000); // 200 msec

    if (_kbhit()) { // if key was pressed during sleep
        int key = getch();
        // you can check key value here
        notDeadAnimation();
    } else {
        dead = true;
        deadAnimation();
    }
}
```