# Stopping long-sleep threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-sleep

Let's suppose I have a thread which should perform some task periodically but this period is <del>6 times each hour</del> 12 times each hour (every 5 minutes), I've often seen code which controls the thread loop with a *is_running* flag which is checked every loop, like this:

```
std::atomic<bool> is_running;

void start()
{
    is_running.store(true);
    std::thread { thread_function }.detach();
}

void stop()
{
    is_running.store(false);
}

void thread_function()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    while (is_running.load())
    {
        // do some task...
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5min);
    }
}
```

But if the `stop()` function is called, let's say, 1 millisecond after `start()` the thread would be alive for 299999 additional milliseconds until it awakes, checks the flag, and die.

Is my understanding correct? How to avoid keeping alive (but sleeping) a thread which should have been ended? My best approach until now is the following:

```
void thread_function()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    while (is_running.load())
    {
        // do some task...
        for (unsigned int b = 0u, e = 1500u; is_running.load() && (b != e); ++b)
        {
            // 1500 * 200 = 300000ms = 5min
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a less-dirty and more straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: _6 times each hour (every 5 minutes)_, well 12 times each hours or every 10 minutes? :)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie what a fail! Thanks, I'll correct it! :)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable, see first sentence there. Instead of sleeping for a fixed amount of time, you enter a signallable wait state for that amount of time so other threads can still interrupt you

Comment: Another option is [boost::basic_waitable_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer.html).

Comment: Should your thread do every 5 minutes some work or the first time after 5 minutes and then sleep another 5 minutes after he finished his work? If the first is your case then I would (on windows) create a timer which creates every 5 minutes a thread which does some work. When creating the thread is too much overhead I would use the threadpool.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use a condition variable.  You wait on the condition variable *or* 5 minutes passing.  Remember to check for spurious wakeups.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

I cannot find a good stack overflow post on how to use a condition variable in a minute or two of google searching.  The tricky part is realizing that the `wait` can wake up with neither 5 minutes passing, nor a signal being sent.  The cleanest way to handle this is to use the wait methods with a lambda that double-checks that the wakeup was a "good" one.

[here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) is some sample code over at cppreference that uses `wait_until` with a lambda.  (`wait_for` with a lambda is equivalent to `wait_until` with a lambda).  I modified it slightly.

Here is an version:

```
struct timer_killer {
  // returns false if killed:
  template<class R, class P>
  bool wait_for( std::chrono::duration<R,P> const& time ) const {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    return !cv.wait_for(lock, time, [&]{return terminate;});
  }
  void kill() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    terminate=true; // should be modified inside mutex lock
    cv.notify_all(); // it is safe, and *sometimes* optimal, to do this outside the lock
  }
  // I like to explicitly delete/default special member functions:
  timer_killer() = default;
  timer_killer(timer_killer&&)=delete;
  timer_killer(timer_killer const&)=delete;
  timer_killer& operator=(timer_killer&&)=delete;
  timer_killer& operator=(timer_killer const&)=delete;
private:
  mutable std::condition_variable cv;
  mutable std::mutex m;
  bool terminate = false;
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66f8b2ee5f9d55e8).

You create a `timer_killer` in a shared spot.  Client threads can `wait_for( time )`.  If it returns false, it means you where killed before your wait was complete.

The controlling thread just calls `kill()` and everyone doing a `wait_for` gets a `false` return.

Note that there is some contention (locking of the mutex), so this isn't suitable for infinite threads (but few things are).  Consider using a scheduler if you need to have an unbounded number of tasks that are run with arbitrary delays instead of a full thread per delayed repeating task -- each real thread is upwards of a megabyte of system address space used (just for the stack).

Comment: Should 'std::unique_lock<std::mutex>' be 'std::lock_guard<std::mutex>' in kill method?

Comment: @user Why?  I guess, but the benefit is small if detectible.

Comment: If you don't call lock.lock(), it doesn't do anything I think.

Comment: @user1633272 No, unique lock is just a movable lock guard.  You can create an unlocked unique lock with a mutex, but that isn't the default way they are created.

Comment: The condition variable `cv` should also be declared as `mutable`, not only the mutex `m`.

Comment: @kaip fixed, also modified kill to take into account modern compiler optimization of cv.

Comment: if it's safe to call `cv.notify_all()` like you indicated in your answer why don't you surround the first 2 lines in `kill()` in inner scope so lock will unlock before `cv.notify_all()` ?

Comment: @SubMachine Because modern compilers generate optimal code if you do it this way, reportedly.  Basically they defer the "actual" notification to the point where the mutex releases.  For a short period, compilers generated faster code if you unlocked the mutex before notifying, but as they matured the other path became better.  So I have started doing that.  I have not personally profiled the difference; I am relying on people far more familiar with clang and other compiler internals who told me it was faster.

Comment: Isn't the `unique_lock` defined in `kill` redundant?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi No; as a rule of thumb, you MUST hold the mutex associated with the condition variable in some interval between modifying a cv-mutex associated state and signaling using the cv.  There is a race condition otherwise that can lead to the signal being missed.  In this case, `terminate` is also a non-atomic; reading it in one thread and writing it in another is a race condition unless synchronized (but making it atomic wouldn't fix the other problem).  So it is needed for 2 reasons, both of which are sufficient to require that mutex.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sorry was confused about `unique_lock` vs `scoped_lock` vs etc. I thought `unique_lock` didn't use the RAII pattern and you had to manually call un/lock - which is why I thought it was redundant since you didn't call those methods. nevermind

Answer (score 5):

There are two traditional ways you could do this.

You could use a timed wait on a condition variable, and have the other thread signal your periodic thread to wake up and die when it's time.

Alternately you could `poll` on a pipe with your sleep as a timeout instead of of sleeping. Then you just write a byte to the pipe and the thread wakes up and can exit.