# Not working array loop

Tags: c++

Why is this not working. I Just want loading like effects. I just compiled the code the g++ compiler. It take time and just print `* * * B R E A K * * *`. There is no difference between per letter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int wait = 1000000000;
    char text[] = {"* * * B R E A K * * *"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        cout << text[i];

        for(int j = 0; j < wait; j++)
            ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect that there will be "difference between per letter"?

Comment: It appears to work as designed. What are you trying to do differently?

Comment: You can't rely on the second loop waiting at all, the whole thing could be optimized out.

Comment: Use some sort of timer to do the pause, the empty loop can be completely optimized out by an optimizing compiler. Also prefer `std::string` over `char text[]`, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sleep for milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds)

Comment: I am just new to c++ but can you explain what " optimized out by an optimizing compiler " means?. Thanks in advance..

Comment: When your compiler runs over your code, it looks for opportunities to make your program run faster. When it sees your loop, it notices that it doesn't matter and excludes it from the compilation process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your wait loop is likely optimized out from the code because the compiler can see that it has no effect.   Try to do a [nano-sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) instead, like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std; 
int main()
{
   char text[]={"* * * B R E A K * * *"};
   for(int i=0;i<21;i++)
   {
      cerr<<text[i];
      usleep(100000);
   }
}
```

Also, `std::cout` is buffered, which means that it will not write until there is a newline, program terminates or you flush -- for simplicity change the `cout` to `cerr` which is non-buffered....

Comment: Thanks.. Maybe I can also flush the buffer using manipulator cout <<flush or cout.flush()