# Pause function execute , in this time do nothing. c++

Tags: c++, clock

```
void PauseFor( int seconds)
{
    clock_t temp;
    temp = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
    while (clock() < temp) {}

}
```

Ok, this is my function.
I want to make stop executing code for 2 seconds in this time do nothing.

Example:

1. RUN FUNCTION
2. after firs run , pause 2 seconds.
3. In this time 2 seconds do nothing.
4. after 2 seconds, you can run function again.

What i want to to ?
I want to stop using function for 2 seconds, In this time 2 seconds nothing happen..

Thanks :)

```
MyFunction()
{
//bla bla bla do something
    PauseFor(2);

}
```

First run `MyFunction()`  after first run , 2 seconds can't run.. after 2 seconds run again

Simply, a return false for 2 seconds

Comment: use the `sleep` function - also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds

Comment: The sleep function, it's different. I don't need sleep. Read again my question :D

Comment: The `clock` function is not a reliable timer function, and returns different things on different platforms. Besides, most operating systems contains native functions to put process to sleep for some amount of time, in a way that won't use CPU. See e.g. [`nanosleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) on POSIX (e.g. Linux and OSX) platforms, or [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows.

Comment: But your `PauseFor` (if it works) is the exact same thing as `sleep` (or `Sleep`), it cause the process to stop doing any work for around two seconds. The difference is that your function will max out the CPU core your process is running on which prevents other processes from using it.

Comment: @user5546877 Is your application multi-threaded? In other words: Could anyone call the function while it’s sleeping? If not, `sleep()` should suffice. Downvoted because of unclear question.

Comment: Guys, sleep()  pause executing for x seconds and the run automaticay...

Comment: I don't want to run after 2 seconds automaticaly, just when i call. that function

Comment: @user5546877 So what shall happen when the pause finishes? A program cannot just “do nothing” until you “trap” it using active wait (`while`) or something like `sleep()`.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you want, but do you mean that in youe example the `MyFunction` should return when you call `PauseFor` and let some other code run, and when the `PauseFor` function is done the `MyFunction` should resume after the `PauseFor` call? Then no that's not really possible in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
```

Comment: Sorry man, but this is a c++11 feature, i'am not using c++11.

Comment: @user5546877 are we supposed to be psychic? It is your responsibility to state in your question what you use. Voting to close it for unclarity.