# Wait function for one section of code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to pause one section of code. I've tried doing a for loop which isn't very effective and I only want to pause one section.

Would wait() work or does that pause the whole program?

I'm making a game for my course and the only way I can think of to make AI to move at a set speed is to pause them and move every 1-3 seconds (for example).

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Edit: I was apparently being an idiot. Problem solved without any wait() functions. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: If that 'section' of code is executed by a particular thread, usleep() for unix (and probably Sleep() for windows) pauses only that thread, the others continue.

Comment: Is this windows or console program? What do you mean by "section of code"? What `wait()` function are you referring too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of how are you running the AI. If the AI has a thread that you can pause, that may work. But I personally would go for another approach:

- Try to make the velocity relative to the delta time of the previous frame.

  ```
  Movement+=velocity*dt;  //velocity per second * time of previous frame in seconds
  ```
- Have a fixed framerate and use the magic number (your fixed delta time) to achieve the same effect than before.

(sleep [Sleep for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds))

- Use a counter and an if to run that section of your code only in certain moments.

  ```
  ...
  time+=dt;
  if (time>3){
  ...
  time=0.0f;
  }
  ```