# Delay an output in C++ using 'ctime' library

Tags: c++, windows

How do I delay an output in C++? I tried searching for similar questions, but I didn't find any solution which makes use of the 'ctime' library. Help please.

Comment: This way of asking, you will have a "delay" in finding the answer

Comment: You need to re-phrase your question and show what you have tried

Comment: You could use `std::time()` to get the current time an then use a loop until `std::time()` tells you that you have been looping for long enough?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613664/1460794) answer.

You could use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));`

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    int x{3000};
    std::cout << "Start waiting\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
    std::cout << "Done waiting\n";
    return 0;
}
```