# Function to make program pause or sleep C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, time, sleep, pause

I am trying to find a way to pause or sleep my simple c++ program such as the `time.sleep(x)` in Python. Is there an equivalent in C++? An example of where I would want to use this is in here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 100 ; x++) {
        cout << 100 - x << " bottles of beer on the wall, "
             << 100 - x << " bottles of beer!\nTake one down pass it around "
             << 100 - (x + 1)  << " bottles of beer on the wall\n\n";
             //enter sleep here to pause before next output
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds or reference to c++ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sleep(ms)` function from WinAPI or POSIX `usleep(mcrsec)`

Comment: How would I use POSIX since I believe it is more than just a library. Do you have a good source in which I could read or learn about it?