# Why does this output 4 times for each ‘for’ iteration

Tags: c++

I’m trying to make a basic timer, this code seems to print out the number of milliseconds correctly based on the value in `duration`

But can someone tell me why it prints the output 4 times for each ‘tick’regardless of what the value of `duration` is, and how to correct it so that it only outputs once on every ‘tick’ set in `duration`? I’m sure it must be something simple I’m overlooking but I’m still learning the basics of C++ and I can’t see the error.

I’m running it on the iOS “Mobile C” app, but I don’t imagine that that would be what’s causing the problem.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    int duration = 100;

    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 100)
    {
        auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto millis = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now - start).count();

        if (millis % duration == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "millis: " << millis << std::endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (1)` is an infinite loop and you have no `break`, `return`, `goto` or `longjmp` statement *in* the loop. Are you sure that's what you want? That it happens to run 4 times while `millis % duration == 0` on your machine is purely a coincidence. On a faster or slower machine it would output more or fewer times.

Comment: Instead of performing % operation to do the timer, why not use the sleep function instead? , based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds, just wait and print when the sleep duration is over

Comment: I was just using that to keep the loop going while I figure out how to make something happen at specific intervals. I did that to simulate the Arduino loop. I’m trying to work on some Arduino code without having to use the actual Arduino IDE and a board, so I’m looking for a way to simulate what the Arduino millis() function does.

Comment: I edited the code to get rid of the infinite loop, it didn’t change the behavior.

Comment: @dee cue  -  I will look into using the sleep function, at a first glance it’s over my head, but looks like a good thing to learn about. I’m still working my way through “C Programming” book and about 20 pages into the C++ Primer, so I’m just not there yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I'm still new here I can't post a comment but the reason you are getting that output 4 times is because that if statement is true 4 times for that one millisecond on your machine like Jesper Juhl was saying.  Consider using a `bool` to make sure it only runs once.  Something like

```
bool hasRun = false;
if (millis % duration == 0)
    {
        if (!hasRun)
        {
            std::cout << "millis: " << millis << std::endl;
            hasRun = true;
        }
    }
else
    hasRun = false;
```

Then you would be able to keep you infinite Arduino simulation loop like you mentioned in the comments but only have the statement ring true once per `duration`.

Comment: Re: "I can't post a comment" -- that's a good thing, since this is an answer, not a comment. <g>

Comment: Thanks @PeteBecker.  I would have liked to get some more information before just going for it but I hope this helps the original poster.