# I want to print the text slowly with the "cout" command but i dont really find any solution

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to print a text slowly letter by letter like in this example

```
//example
int main()
{
    string message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \nconsectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, porro \nnesciunt laboriosam adipisci provident eum?\n";
    slow_print(message, 30);

    return 0;
}
```

but i want to have this effec twith the cout command but i dont find any solutions. If someone know how to fix this so please helpe me

Comment: why did you tag c++-cli? Is this c++-cli ?

Comment: write a loop that prints individual characters and add a sleep.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613664/4117728

Comment: Write a wrapper around `cout` that adds a delay between printing each character. Then use your new wrapper instead of `cout` directly.  Straight forward.

Comment: You could print each character individually after a delay that you could specify with the ctime library.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, lets do this using `cout`. `cout` alone cannot do it, you need some io-manipulator or similar. I will use a type to indicate a string should be printed slowly:

```
struct slowly_printing_string { 
    std::string data; 
    long int delay; 
};
```

Next, we provide an output operator for this type:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const slowly_printing_string& s) {
    for (const auto& c : s.data) {
        out << c << std::flush;        
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(s.delay));
    }
    return out;
}
```

It prints individual characters, flushes the stream (otherwise it could happen that you only see the full string at some later point), and waits for the specified time.

You can call it like this:

```
std::cout << slowly_printing_string{"hello world",1000};
```

[Full Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OAbOpSLiAeJRRfbI)

Answer (score 2):

I can do this by this code, but I don't recommend this code if you are developping to an enterprise:

```
#include <iostream>

#define LENGTH(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

using namespace std;

void printSlowCharacters(char * strToPrint) {
    while(*strToPrint) {
        cout << *strToPrint++ << endl;
        system("sleep 5");
    }
}


int main() {
    char * nome = "Davi";
    printSlowCharacters(nome);

    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#include <windows.h>` and then in a loop you would print each character individually and intertwine it with `Sleep(time_in_ms)`.

How is it possible? Each `std::string` is an array of characters, which is similar to `char*`, that way you can access each character by its index.

Comment: If you use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) you can generalize this advice  beyond Visual C++

Comment: an array of characters is not equal to `char*`. Arrays are not pointers!

Comment: Your solution assumes the Window's operating system.  There are other operating systems out there:  MicroCOs, Wind River, Linux, etc.