# Does Buffer Source change the pixel format to `pix_fmt` or does it only read the input as if it was that format?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav

I am learning `libav` and related things.
I came across [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/filtering__video_8c_source.html#l00110) example from the ffmpeg documentation:

```c
     /* buffer video source: the decoded frames from the decoder will be inserted here. */
     snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
             "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
             dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
             time_base.num, time_base.den,
             dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);
  
     ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                                        args, NULL, filter_graph);
```

If I specify a `pix_fmt` other than `dec_ctx->pix_fmt` (for example, `rgb24`), will this buffer source convert the pixel format to `rgb24`, or will it instead *read* the source as *if* it was in `rgb24` format, thereby causing incorrect decoding?

And what happens if I set a different `video_size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `pix_fmt` to rgb24, converts the pixel format to rgb24.

---

Without much knowledge about filter graphs, we may execute the code, and check the output.

For displaying the output frame, I replaced the "Trivial ASCII grayscale display" with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) method `cv::imshow`.
Setting up a project that uses both Libav and OpenCV requires some initial effort...

Here is the output frame with the original code (output is Grayscale):
[image]

Here is the output frame with `AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24` pixel format (output is BGR):
[image]
Note: BGR is used (instead of RGB) because OpenCV convention for color ordering is BGR.

---

When BGR format is used there is a warning message:

> Changing video frame properties on the fly is not supported by all filters.

It is probably not the best practice to set `pix_fmt` in such way...

---

Complete code:

```
//https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Nicolas George
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Stefano Sabatini
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */

 /**
  * @file
  * API example for decoding and filtering
  * @example filtering_video.c
  */

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 /* for usleep */
#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <unistd.h>
#else
//Windows - use C++11 for usleep
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
}


#define DO_TEST_PIX_FMT_BGR24   //If defined, test pixel format BGR24


const char* filter_descr = "scale=78:24,transpose=cclock";
/* other way:
   scale=78:24 [scl]; [scl] transpose=cclock // assumes "[in]" and "[out]" to be input output pads respectively
 */

static AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx;
static AVCodecContext* dec_ctx;
AVFilterContext* buffersink_ctx;
AVFilterContext* buffersrc_ctx;
AVFilterGraph* filter_graph;
static int video_stream_index = -1;
static int64_t last_pts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

static int open_input_file(const char* filename)
{
    AVCodec* dec;
    int ret;

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
        return ret;
    }

    /* select the video stream */
    ret = av_find_best_stream(fmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find a video stream in the input file\n");
        return ret;
    }
    video_stream_index = ret;

    /* create decoding context */
    dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
    if (!dec_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(dec_ctx, fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codecpar);

    /* init the video decoder */
    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(dec_ctx, dec, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video decoder\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int init_filters(const char* filters_descr)
{
    char args[512];
    int ret = 0;
    const AVFilter* buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    const AVFilter* buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
    AVFilterInOut* outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut* inputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVRational time_base = fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->time_base;

#ifdef DO_TEST_PIX_FMT_BGR24
    enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = { AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE };  //Replace AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8 with AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24
#else
    enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = { AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE };
#endif
    

    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if (!outputs || !inputs || !filter_graph) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    /* buffer video source: the decoded frames from the decoder will be inserted here. */
#ifdef DO_TEST_PIX_FMT_BGR24
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
        "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
        dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, (int)AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24 /*dec_ctx->pix_fmt*/,    //Replace dec_ctx->pix_fmt with AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24
        time_base.num, time_base.den,
        dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);
#else
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
        "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
        dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
        time_base.num, time_base.den,
        dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);
#endif

    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
        args, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer source\n");
        goto end;
    }

    /* buffer video sink: to terminate the filter chain. */
    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
        NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer sink\n");
        goto end;
    }

    ret = av_opt_set_int_list(buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts", pix_fmts,
        AV_PIX_FMT_NONE, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output pixel format\n");
        goto end;
    }

    /*
     * Set the endpoints for the filter graph. The filter_graph will
     * be linked to the graph described by filters_descr.
     */

     /*
      * The buffer source output must be connected to the input pad of
      * the first filter described by filters_descr; since the first
      * filter input label is not specified, it is set to "in" by
      * default.
      */
    outputs->name = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    outputs->pad_idx = 0;
    outputs->next = NULL;

    /*
     * The buffer sink input must be connected to the output pad of
     * the last filter described by filters_descr; since the last
     * filter output label is not specified, it is set to "out" by
     * default.
     */
    inputs->name = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    inputs->pad_idx = 0;
    inputs->next = NULL;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filters_descr,
        &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

end:
    avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
    avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);

    return ret;
}

static void display_frame(const AVFrame* frame, AVRational time_base)
{
    //int x, y;
    //uint8_t* p0, * p;
    int64_t delay;

    const AVRational av_time_base_q = {1, AV_TIME_BASE};

    if (frame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
        if (last_pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
            /* sleep roughly the right amount of time;
             * usleep is in microseconds, just like AV_TIME_BASE. */
            delay = av_rescale_q(frame->pts - last_pts,
                time_base, av_time_base_q);
            if (delay > 0 && delay < 1000000)
#ifdef __GNUC__
                usleep(delay);
#else
                //Windows
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(delay));
#endif
        }
        last_pts = frame->pts;
    }

    /* Trivial ASCII grayscale display. */
    //p0 = frame->data[0];
    //puts("\033c");
    //for (y = 0; y < frame->height; y++) {
    //    p = p0;
    //    for (x = 0; x < frame->width; x++)
    //        putchar(" .-+#"[*(p++) / 52]);
    //    putchar('\n');
    //    p0 += frame->linesize[0];
    //}
    //fflush(stdout);

    //Use OpenCV for display
#ifdef DO_TEST_PIX_FMT_BGR24
    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(frame->height, frame->width, CV_8UC3, frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0]);    //3 Color channels (BGR)
#else
    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(frame->height, frame->width, CV_8UC1, frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0]);    //1 Color channels (Grayscale)
#endif
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::waitKey(1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int ret;
    AVPacket* packet;
    AVFrame* frame;
    AVFrame* filt_frame;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    filt_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    packet = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!frame || !filt_frame || !packet) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate frame or packet\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((ret = open_input_file(argv[1])) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = init_filters(filter_descr)) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* read all packets */
    while (1) {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, packet)) < 0)
            break;

        if (packet->stream_index == video_stream_index) {
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(dec_ctx, packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while sending a packet to the decoder\n");
                break;
            }

            while (ret >= 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    break;
                }
                else if (ret < 0) {
                    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while receiving a frame from the decoder\n");
                    goto end;
                }

                frame->pts = frame->best_effort_timestamp;

                /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
                if (av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, frame, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF) < 0) {
                    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
                    break;
                }

                /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
                while (1) {
                    ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, filt_frame);
                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                        break;
                    if (ret < 0)
                        goto end;
                    display_frame(filt_frame, buffersink_ctx->inputs[0]->time_base);
                    av_frame_unref(filt_frame);
                }
                av_frame_unref(frame);
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(packet);
    }
end:
    avfilter_graph_free(&filter_graph);
    avcodec_free_context(&dec_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&fmt_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_frame_free(&filt_frame);
    av_packet_free(&packet);

    if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        char errbuf[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        av_make_error_string(errbuf, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, ret);    
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred: %s\n", errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! also, what happens if I set a different video_size in the buffer source? will it resize the video then? if so, will the output of the filter be resized as well, or will it be resized back?

Comment: how do you know that it actually does convert? did you write the code especially to check it, or is it somewhere in the doc, or did you dig into ffmpeg sources?

Comment: What are the differences between the  code from [your link](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/filtering__video_8c_source.html#l00110) and the code in my post? I looked for more up to date example an found it in [GitHub](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c). I added minor changes (related to warning due to building the code as C++ instead of C) and adding the OpenCV part.

Comment: I know the code actually does convert, because the pixel format of the input is not BGR and not Grayscale, it is YUV.

Comment: For chaining the output size, modify `const char* filter_descr = "scale=78:24,transpose=cclock"` to `const char* filter_descr = "scale=320:240"` (for example). The `scale` filter is responsible for changing the size.

Comment: I think the right way to modify the pixel format is chaining `filter_descr`. Keep the argument `dec_ctx->pix_fmt` in `snprintf`. Add `format` filter to `filter_descr`. Example: `const char* filter_descr = "format=bgr24,scale=320:240"`. The output is BGR24, and there are no warnings.

Comment: I conclude that doing this `snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d", dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, (int)AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24 ...` is a mistake...

Comment: If you do not set `pix_fmts` for sink does it simply use `px_fmt` from buffersrc?

Comment: @DanM. The C interface of FFmpeg is too complicated and I don't know the answer. I recommend you to execute the code, and inspect the results.

Answer (score 1):

All of the parameters you specify for the buffer source are to "[describe] the frames that will be passed to this filter" [1](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/structAVBufferSrcParameters.html)

You can set the parameters in two ways: as a text string like in your example [2](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/buffersrc_8c_source.html#l00300):

```
/* buffer video source: the decoded frames from the decoder will be inserted here. */
 snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
         "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
         dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
         time_base.num, time_base.den,
         dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

 ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                                    args, NULL, filter_graph);
```

Or, in an AVBufferSrcParameters struct passed using av_buffersrc_parameters_set [3](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/group__lavfi__buffersrc.html#ga398cd2a84f8b4a588197ab9d90135048):

```
/* buffer video source: the decoded frames from the decoder will be inserted here. */
 AVBufferSrcParameters *params = av_buffersrc_parameters_alloc();
 params->width = dec_ctx->width;
 params->height = dec_ctx->height;
 params->format = dec_ctx->pix_fmt;
 params->time_base.num = time_base.num;
 params->time_base.den = time_base.den;
 params->sample_aspect_ratio.num = dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num;
 params->sample_aspect_ratio.den = dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den;

 ret = av_buffersrc_parameters_set(buffersrc_ctx, params);

 av_free(params);
```

Either way the parameters are sent, they go to the same internal structure and are used in the same way. [4](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/buffersrc_8c_source.html#l00097) [2](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/buffersrc_8c_source.html#l00300)

> The frames later passed to this filter must conform to those parameters. [3](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/group__lavfi__buffersrc.html#ga398cd2a84f8b4a588197ab9d90135048)