# would clog and cout in c++ behave differently in outputing the value?

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, clog

I am expecting a similar behavior for Cout and Clog since both are buffered outputs. But when i am trying, it comes out different.

COUT:

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World" ;
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: Nothing --> Since Cout is not flushed

CLOG:

```
int main()
{
    clog<<"Hello World" ;
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `Hello World`

**Question**: Both COUT and CLOG are buffered, so why not the output is same. How is "Hello World" being printed without the buffer being flushed

Comment: `while(1);` is undefined and the output of the two programs could be anything

Comment: I suggest to use some `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));` instead of the infinite loop

Comment: What is `clog`?  Most error handlers flush automatically so that you always have the most current information in the log.

Comment: @NathanOliver • [`std::clog`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/clog) is a buffered stream, and is synchonized with stdio, and "safe" to use concurrently in multiple threads (ignoring the interleaving issue).  In contrast to `std::cerr` which is unbuffered.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand the purpose of the infinite loop. If you are trying to put the thread to sleep check this post [StackOverflow post about thread sleeping in cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds),

Secondly, if you want to flush the stream use `std::cout << std::flush;`.

As for the difference between those: basically clog is a rarely used output stream similar to cerr. Basically clog outputs to stderr, similar to cerr, and not stdout. Checking these might help you understand the difference:  [COUT vs CERR vs CLOG](https://m.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/108474/),
[Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-difference-between-cerr-and-clog-streams-in-cplusplus).

Now onto the difference between stdout and stderr. Stdout is always buffered and is flushed automatically at a convenient time or when requested explicitly to do so, meanwhile stderr is not fully buffered and always prints stuff immediately, without needing to be flushed explicitly.